# Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, we will be appointing some provisional Moderators to fill that role.

We need your help. Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

### The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation.
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> `<h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>`
>
> `<h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>`
>
> `Notes:`
>
> `<why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>`
>
> `---`
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> `I accept/decline this nomination`
>
> `I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are`…
>
> `etc.`

Comment: How many moderators are you looking for?

Comment: @JasonAller It's typically three, though there are a couple beta sites with two or four. On the overwhelming majority of betas, though, there are three. Graduated sites may have more.

Comment: What do we feel critical mass looks like re: public elections?

Comment: @PatW Public elections aren't done until *much* later. It used to only happen on graduated sites; [Crypto.SE] is having one now, but it's still only for graduated sites or beta-but-not-really-beta sites.

Answer (score 10):

**[Feetwet](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/10/feetwet)**

**[Meta Profile](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10/feetwet)**

---

I would be happy to serve as a moderator.  I typically have a SE window open whenever I'm working, which is typically 8AM-10PM Eastern U.S. time.

As a moderator my primary concern would be taking care of flags and review items so the site keeps running smoothly.  My goal would be to adhere to the [minimalist Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you're willing to do this.

Comment: I appreciate your contributions where I find them.  A +1 from me to you, sir.

Answer (score 7):

#### [jimsug](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/58/jimsug)

#### [meta](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/jimsug)

In short: Sydney hours, past moderation experience, and *laissez-faire* moderation.

---

Some of you may have seen me on ELL, where I'm a bit more in my element. However, I have been responsible for a number of communities, both in the real world and online, and I certainly have an interest in law, as a law student. I live in Sydney and so I'm usually active between about 6pm to 10pm, but also keep a tab open between 9am and 5pm (Sydney time).

I would pre-emptively address my lack of recent activity on main with the fact that, as a student, I'm ethically conflicted - many of my questions would relate to my studies, and so I'm not sure whether it would be appropriate to ask assignment questions, for instance. Furthermore, my questions would relate to Australian law, and I'm not entirely sure what kind of a presence Australian lawyers have here.

In terms of the site, I would love to see this site become a flourishing source of expert answers like many others, even if they're still in beta. I have a reasonably *laissez-faire* disposition towards moderation, intervening only when required.

Answer (score 6):

**[Jason Aller](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/62/jason-aller)**

**[Meta Profile](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62/jason-aller)**

As there has not been a rush of more qualified candidates I'll nominate myself.

---

I'd like to see this site succeed and graduate into another healthy and positive member of the Stack Exchange family of sites. I'm only an enthusiastic amateur with regard to the law. Like feetwet I would try to follow a minimalist approach as a moderator.

One task I see for moderators early on with this site is to listen to the community as it experiments to find ways to succeed at the intersection between Law and the Stack Exchange way. Then to take this evolving community understanding of itself and update the [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) and other materials to help new folks understand the community purpose and goals.

I live in Davis, CA, so I am generally active on this site from 8:00am to 10:00pm PST. I have volunteered in the past with [CourtListener](https://www.courtlistener.com/) which is part of the [Free Law Project](http://freelawproject.org/), but would not let that impact my moderation.

Answer (score 1):

[cnst](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/65/cnst)

[meta](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users/65/cnst)

[network](http://stackexchange.com/users/1137539/cnst)

I live in Austin, previously Waterloo and Kitchener, also lived in NorCal, in the UK and in Russia, I'm a software engineer, mostly interested in consumer law of California and Texas, especially landlord and tenant relations.

I'm very conservative when it comes to moderation — if it's not broken, don't fix it.

Answer (score -2):

As the creator of the Area51 proposal for this site, I am definitely eager to see this site succeed and I would therefore be willing to be involved in moderating this site.

Just like feetwet, I too subscribe to the philosophy of minimal moderator intervention in order to allow the site to flourish in its own unique way.

I too would pre-emptively address my lack of recent activity on main with the fact that, as a student, I'm ethically conflicted - many of my questions would relate to my studies, and so I'm not sure whether it would be appropriate to ask assignment questions, for instance.

Comment: No questions, answers, edits or reviews yet...

Comment: @curiousdannii, No longer true :)

Comment: it's good that you're using the site now, but it was true yesterday.

Comment: @curiousdannii, yes but 3 people upvoted your comment after I had started participating.

Comment: Well I'm not responsible for that. Can't vote on my own comments of course!

Comment: @curiousdannii, understood.  I just wanted to point out to the rest of the community that it was no longer true :)

Comment: Just a note - it's weird to see you say that you're ethically conflicted when you've copied half your nomination from mine, verbatim. It's also weird to see you say that you're _preemptively_ addressing lack of activity when you very clearly did it in response to the first comment. Good luck!

Comment: @jimsug, thanks :) Good luck to you too!

Answer (score -4):

[Andrew](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/432/andrew?tab=profile)

[Meta Profile](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users/432/andrew?tab=profile)

Notes:
I am currently a law student. Answering and moderating the questions here will not only allow me to better the site, but also better my legal knowledge.

---

I accept this nomination

I am Andrew/28/Tulsa, OK. I live in Tulsa, OK, so I am generally active on this site from 1pm CST to 10pm cst. Some other things you may want to know about me are I am currently working in Patent Prosecution and Litigation. I was also top of my class in Criminal Law and among the top in, among many classes, Constitutional Law and Intellectual Property. I also enjoy working in Immigration Law.

Comment: Without trying to be harsh, you have no upvoted posts on main, no posts besides this one at all on meta, and you've been here for <24 hours.

Comment: That's absolutely true and not harsh in the slightest. I do believe that I can do a good job at being a moderator. I did not notice that this came to beta until I looked for it today in Area51.

Comment: I don't explicitly doubt that you can be a good Stack Exchange moderator; lack of activity is generally not good at this stage, because moderators will most likely - I think - be picked soon, so some dedication is needed as proof. That's all I'm potentially questioning; thank you for not being offended.

Comment: It is important that you be able to show that you can and have a history of positive contributions to the site prior to becoming a moderator.  Typically most moderators selected have at least 5k rep on another SE Site so they have demonstrated their understanding of the SE standards and process.  Moderators are often not great contributors because they have to spend so much time doing mod work.  There will likely be future opportunities to become a moderator.  I recommend you become an active user here and try with one of those future opportunities.

Comment: I wonder if anyone will reconsider?

Comment: It is too late for the five people who have voted to change their vote now - you would need to edit your post in some way. Having said that, you haven't really been active in the last couple of days.