# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Law's [first moderator election](https://law.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: feetwet] [image: jimsug] [image: cnst]

They'll be replacing [the pro tempore crew](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182/please-welcome-your-new-moderators) shortly — please thank both groups for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new folks as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5307802432045056/0).

Comment: Congratulations to all.

Comment: @feetwet Will you nominate yourself for the 2019 Moderator Election? I hope so. I intended to nominate you (actually both you and phoog) explaining why you should remain, but I just found out that one can only nominate oneself. I think jimsung and cnst are also doing a good job (or at least I have no reasons to doubt it). It's just that there are only two spots up for this election and I am most familiar with your performance as mod.

Comment: @phoog Will you nominate yourself for the 2019 Election? Similar to my comment to feetwet, I've thought of reasons why to nominate you as well (if only SE allowed nominating others, which [it does not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352420/can-i-nominate-someone-else-to-be-a-moderator?rq=1)).