# Proposal for a new ask question modal

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, user-interface

It was suggested in [a comment by Laurel](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/when-is-a-jurisdiction-tag-required-in-a-question?cb=1#comment4217_1844) on [Trish's answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1844/44937) to [Jen's Meta question on jurisdiction tags](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1841/44937) to edit the "Ask Question" modal. I agree that that's a good idea, especially considering the consensus to remove [any-jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/any-jurisdiction). Here's my suggestion for the text, partially based on [the SE default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059/1203059):

> Welcome to Law Stack Exchange! You're ready to ask your first question, and the community is here to help! To help you get the best answers, we've provided some guidance:
>
> If you're interested in answers for a particular jurisdiction, please specify that jurisdiction in a [tag] (link to help page on tags). If you'd like answers from around the world, leave off the jurisdiction tag.
>
> Most of our users are not lawyers, and even those who are do not give legal advice here. The purpose of this site is to answer general questions about the law, [not to apply it to your circumstances] (link to legal advice policy). **Please do not rely on anything you read here.**
>
> Before you post, [search the site] (link to search) to make sure your question hasn't been answered.
>
> 1. Summarize the problem
> 2. Provide details and any research

Answer (score 1):

> Most of our users are not lawyers, and even those who are do not give legal advice here.

I believe this needs a somewhat different wording since some of our biggest pointed users are working in law, though are not licensed everywhere. As such, I propose one of these setups, which might be best referenced by number:

> 1. No user is giving legal advice here, even if they happen to be a lawyer in some area.

> 2. The users of this site are doing so as legal scholars and researchers, not lawyers. Nothing they say is meant as legal advice.

> 3. The users on this site are strictly prohibited from giving legal advice on Law.SE by site rules, regardless of their legal background or licensing in your area.

Comment: We need something as simple as possible that hits the important points that are often missed by first-time users. I think this might be starting to get too long to be useful in a quick-to-read question modal. But that is only my guess.

Comment: so even shorter: "You will not get legal advice here."?

Comment: @Jen if you have an even better proposal or find one of the three most easy, it'd be great to know which. I didn't want to clutter the questions with 3 different, so maybe vote via comment

Comment: I think #1 or #2 would probably be best. IMO, #3 focuses too much on the rules for answerers, when this is being shown to askers.

Comment: I like option 1