# Should we remove [multiple-jurisdiction] along with [any-jurisdiction]?

Tags: discussion, status-review, tags

Considering [the consensus to remove](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/when-is-a-jurisdiction-tag-required-in-a-question) [any-jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/any-jurisdiction), should we also remove [multiple-jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-jurisdiction), currently used on 47 questions?